# Searching ContentDocument with SOSL 'Name Fields' appears to return documents with the search string in the content

Tags: sosl, contentdocument

It looks like when I issue a SOSL statement against NAME FIELDS in ContentDocument, I get documents that have the search string *in the content* as well.

I really need it to just search the name fields, as requested.

Has anyone seen this behaviour / corrected it?

E.g. the following SOSL statements:

In developer console:

```
FIND {Bob} IN NAME FIELDS RETURNING ContentDocument(Id, Title ORDER BY Title) LIMIT 20
```

Or, in Apex

```
FIND :searchString IN NAME FIELDS RETURNING ContentDocument(Id, Title ORDER BY Title) LIMIT :MAX_SEARCH_RESULTS
```